# LTSpice Has bizzare results for high input impedance devices

Tags: simulation, ltspice, spice

While simulating with LTSpice I discovered the simulator gives milliamps of inverting and non-inverting terminal current in op amps and also the same thing for MOSFETs, milliamps into gates. Here is a simple circuit demonstrating the current into a non-inverting terminal with an op amp. I will also put down that I measured only nanoamps of current into op amp inverting and non inverting terminals and also MOSFET gates in Multisim to verify that LTspice is incorrectly giving results, which leads me to believe LTSpice is seriously flawed and this should be reported to developers. Is this normal or is it a bug which should be reported to developers?
[image: Simple Circuit]

[image: Output current for non-inverting terminal]

Another circuit
[image: With 2 inputs]

[image: Inverting terminal current]

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: I just added it.

Comment: @user33915 Why would you imagine that an opamp has zero (very low) input current when the voltage difference between the inputs is 3 V???? Try arranging things so that both inputs are at 3 V and THEN check the input currents.

Comment: Its because op amps have as much as 20Megohms or more of input impedance.

Comment: Updated post with circuit having 2 inputs.

Comment: @user33915 1 V is still just as bad. Linear Technology's LT1001 and LT1002 are ***bipolar opamps***. I suppose you have no idea how a bipolar opamp is designed to work? If you want low currents, you MUST keep the differential between the two inputs well under 100 mV and preferably only a few mV, if possible. Try a 30 mV difference, for example.

Comment: @user33915 These things use diff-pairs. Examine [Figure from page 167 of a book by Abraham Pressman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Hx8W.png). Note the range of differences allowed for? And if you look over that nice picture, you'll see that \$\pm \:30\:\text{mV}\$ is about all you *want* to allow. This is ***not*** a problem with LTspice. This is a ***user*** problem. Totally different kind of *bug*.

Comment: AFAIK LTSpice has realistic device models. A theoretical ideal op-amp draws no current but it is not simulating a theoretical ideal op-amp, it's simulating a LT1002.

Comment: I saw milliamps into MOSFET gates while with the SAME fet in Multisim nanoamps were flowing.

Comment: @user33915 Since this question has been answered, can you post one such (separate question) example for MOSFETs? It could be that you're making a similar mistake, or that LTspice is, indeed flawed (though I am reluctant to say this, but, you never know...).

Comment: I will make a seperate post in the future, however I did see milliamps into MOSFET gates. Give some simulations a try you might find it doing what I am trying to bring up in this topic.

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in comments, opamps don't like their inputs to be as widely different potentials.  That said, I believe LT Spice might be telling the truth.  Take a look at the LT1002 schematic.  Notice the series R and protection diodes between the two inputs.  If the two inputs differ by more than 2 diode drops or about 1.2V, the current will be limited by the two 500 series resistors.

The current into the higher potential input and out of the lower potential input will then be equal to the difference between the two Vin sources, minus 1.2V, all divided by 1k ohms (sorry, no math fonts on my phone).  [image: snipped LT1002 schematic]

Comment: What you did not take into consideration is the fact that LTspice does the same high currents even with FET input op amps, and also milliamps into MOSFET gates. However I do appriciate the elaboration for the LT1002 IC, I am posting this only because I saw nanoamps in Multisim so I thought I might as well put it here that I saw LTspice put milliamps into MOSFET gates.